# Change ListView Image at Runtime Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: android, listview, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Delphi 10.1 Berlin. ListView.ItemAppearance=DynamicAppearance.
I want to change Image in ListViewItem in Runtime.

[image: View]

My code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  k:integer;
begin
  LsvAl.BeginUpdate;
  for k := 0 to LsvAl.ItemCount-1 do
  begin
    if (k mod 2)=0 then
    begin
      TListItemImage(LsvAl.Items[k].Objects.FindDrawable('Imp1')).Bitmap.Assign(Image2.Bitmap); //
      TListItemText(LsvAl.Items[k].Objects.FindDrawable('TxtNum')).TextColor:=$FFFF2346;
    end
    else
    begin
      TListItemImage(LsvAl.Items[k].Objects.FindDrawable('Imp1')).Bitmap.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
      TListItemText(LsvAl.Items[k].Objects.FindDrawable('TxtNum')).TextColor:=$FF009DFE;
    end
  end;
  LsvAl.EndUpdate;
```

end;

In result: all pictures red (Image1 too).

[image: Before]

[image: After]

What am i doing wrong?

[Project source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzuFO8gFa8nSVTlFYVFzME5mV0U)

Comment: OK, I found decision. The problem was in Bitmap.Assign.  Normal way is TListItemImage(LsvAl.Items[k].Objects.FindDrawable('Imp1')).Bitmap:=Image2.Bitmap;

Comment: It's hard to know when to assign() a btimap and when to := a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

where is one addon - after assigning a bitmap you can make Item owner by
AItem.OwnsBitmap := True;